# Merge all .dta files in one folder?

Tags: stata

I have a folder with 36 .dta files which are all structured the same. Each one has 2 fields: RowID and value. Each file also has the same number of rows (2,500). The name of the "value" variable is unique to each file. I would like to construct a loop that loads in the first .dta file and then **merges** the "value" variable from each of the other 35 files. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here are sample data from 3 of the .dta files:

```
Example 1:
input int rowid_ float value_ex_1
 1 0
 2 0
 3 0
 4 1
 5 1
 6 1
 7 1
 8 1
 9 1
10 1

Example 2:
input int rowid_ float value_ex_2
 1 1
 2 0
 3 0
 4 1
 5 1
 6 0
 7 0
 8 0
 9 0
10 0

Example 3:
input int rowid_ float value_ex_3
 1 0
 2 0
 3 0
 4 0
 5 0
 6 1
 7 1
 8 0
 9 0
10 1
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple example? Maybe use dataex from ssc to create small extracts from three files. Then the solution will be straightforward.

Comment: You also seem to mix up append and merge. Append adds more observations (rows) to a data set, and merge adds variables (columns) to observations. Merge creates new observations if they do not exist in the original data set. So, do you want to add 35 variables to the observations in the original data set or does all 35 data sets have new observations with new IDs?

Comment: I added example data from three of the .dta files to the original post above. To clarify, you are correct that I want to merge, rather than append, the datasets.

Comment: Is this of help?: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/large-datasets/   from 8. they start merging files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to loop over all your `.dta files`, first make sure they are named after a logical order (i.e example_1.dta, example_2.dta, example_3.dta etc).

Then, you can load the first dataset and loop over the other ones with a `forvalues` loop:

```
cd "path/to/your/datasets"

use example_1.dta, clear

forvalues i = 2(1)35 { 
    merge 1:1 rowid_ using example_`i'.dta
    drop _merge
}
```